# Android-the method loadUrl() in webView sends POST or GET request?

Tags: android, post, webview, get

i'm working with webview recently and i found 2 methods to load an URL in webView.
For postUrl() the doc said clearly it sends a POST request, but it didn't say anything about loadUrl().
can anybody tell me anything about it?

Comment: Send = POST. Load = GET.

Comment: loadUrl loads from a string by definition all request data in the url is a get.